# I can't set up a new virtual host for some reason

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost

So I did this to set up a new virtual host:

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
sudo touch test
sudo gedit test
```

I have saved this content inside the test file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test.local
DocumentRoot /home/richard/projects/test
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I did:

```
mkdir /home/richard/projects/test
touch /home/richard/projects/test/index.html
sudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

I have edited the hosts file to look like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   richard-desktop
127.0.0.1   test.local
127.0.0.1   test2.local
127.0.0.1   test3.local

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Then I did:

```
sudo a2ensite test
sudo a2dissite default
sudo service apache2 reload
```

I then go in my browser to:

```
http://test.local
```

And it doesn't work, the page is loading forever.

---

Ouput of netstat -plnt |grep 80:

```
richard@richard-desktop:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ sudo netstat -plnt |grep 80
[sudo] password for richard: 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1265/apache2
```

Output of netstat -taupen | grep :80:

```
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:36199      77.67.21.59:80          ESTABLISHED 1000       88789       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56686         127.0.0.1:80            ESTABLISHED 1000       88490       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56775         127.0.0.1:80            ESTABLISHED 1000       87786       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:35054      31.186.231.25:80        TIME_WAIT   0          0           -               
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:37231      64.34.119.12:80         ESTABLISHED 1000       89616       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:60212      173.194.34.99:80        ESTABLISHED 1000       87876       4410/firefox    
tcp        1      0 10.200.32.82:44111      91.189.89.134:80        CLOSE_WAIT  1000       94528       2159/python     
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:46205      173.194.34.97:80        ESTABLISHED 1000       87879       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56684         127.0.0.1:80            ESTABLISHED 1000       93631       4410/firefox    
tcp        1      0 10.200.32.82:44112      91.189.89.134:80        CLOSE_WAIT  1000       94529       2159/python     
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:47009      77.67.21.48:80          ESTABLISHED 1000       96368       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:36200      77.67.21.59:80          ESTABLISHED 1000       88790       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:35053      31.186.231.25:80        TIME_WAIT   0          0           -               
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:33628      92.123.67.88:80         ESTABLISHED 1000       93931       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:46999      77.67.21.48:80          ESTABLISHED 1000       88794       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:50668      64.34.119.101:80        ESTABLISHED 1000       87923       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:46991      77.67.21.48:80          ESTABLISHED 1000       96363       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56681         127.0.0.1:80            ESTABLISHED 1000       93629       4410/firefox    
tcp        1      0 10.200.32.82:58695      91.189.89.144:80        CLOSE_WAIT  1000       7844        2011/ubuntu-geoip-p
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:34946      173.194.67.95:80        ESTABLISHED 1000       93950       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:56595      77.67.21.56:80          ESTABLISHED 1000       93933       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:57734      77.67.21.35:80          ESTABLISHED 1000       93956       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:36203      77.67.21.59:80          ESTABLISHED 1000       88793       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56679         127.0.0.1:80            ESTABLISHED 1000       93627       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56677         127.0.0.1:80            ESTABLISHED 1000       86821       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:49652      50.112.101.148:80       ESTABLISHED 1000       93939       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:44859      184.73.242.29:80        ESTABLISHED 1000       96374       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:47811      23.21.113.66:80         ESTABLISHED 1000       87908       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:46996      77.67.21.48:80          ESTABLISHED 1000       88791       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:52730      173.194.41.133:80       ESTABLISHED 1000       93958       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:32952      64.34.119.13:80         ESTABLISHED 1000       96383       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56678         127.0.0.1:80            ESTABLISHED 1000       87612       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56897         127.0.0.1:80            ESTABLISHED 1000       93903       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:36197      77.67.21.59:80          ESTABLISHED 1000       88787       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:36202      77.67.21.59:80          ESTABLISHED 1000       88792       4410/firefox    
tcp        0      0 10.200.32.82:36198      77.67.21.59:80          ESTABLISHED 1000       88788       4410/firefox    
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          13912       -               
tcp6     290      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:56678         ESTABLISHED 0          0           -               
tcp6     300      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:56681         ESTABLISHED 0          0           -               
tcp6     290      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:56897         ESTABLISHED 0          0           -               
tcp6     289      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:56686         ESTABLISHED 0          0           -               
tcp6     290      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:56775         ESTABLISHED 0          0           -               
tcp6     290      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:56684         ESTABLISHED 0          0           -               
tcp6     290      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:56677         ESTABLISHED 0          0           -               
tcp6     290      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:56679         ESTABLISHED 0          0           -
```

Comment: Can you give the output of command `netstat -taupen | grep :80` ?

Comment: Added output of netstat -taupen | grep :80

Comment: Could you check your apache logs when you do the reload, and for the first connection ?

Comment: Please provide the output of `netstat -plnt |grep 80`

Comment: @adaptr Updated to my question.

Comment: As root, obviously.

Comment: @adaprt Updated my question.

Comment: problem is sure that it is not listening on ipv4 address.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the Listening port. According to your output, it is listening only on IPv6 but not on IPv4 thats why the page is always loading..

According to your output of netstat command:

```
tcp6       0      0     :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          13912       -
```

You have to have change your /etc/apache2/ports.conf to make it listen on the ipv4 address also.

Add the following line in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` file:

`Listen 0.0.0.0:80`

Comment: I already have that line in ports.conf

Comment: Then it should listen on 0.0.0.0:80..Are u sure that the output of `netstat -taupen | grep :80` command u gave is complete..

Comment: Yes, it's complete. I have the Listen line in ports.conf so I don't know what could be the problem.

Comment: Can u trying running it in some alternative port ?